# php - unwanted session results

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array

i am developing a web application,which has 3 pages.
first is **index.php**
which has search bar on which user searches.
second is **search.php**
which displays the search results like **result_1,result_2,result_3** with info(title,description,url) when user click on any result it send the user to final page i.e show.php
and  third page is **show.php**

on which info is displayed for the result which user has clicked.
for eg(corresponding url content will be displayed using iframe)

i tried using two dimensional session array,which is working not correctly.
when user click on any result,some other result's info is displaying on show.php

i check the session array content by `print_r`,it had unnecessary content.
someone help me in this i am sharing my code snippet.
**search.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                        {   

                          $title = $row['title'];
                          $description = $row['description'];
                          $url = $row['content_url'];
                          $icon = $row['thumb_icon_url'];


   $_SESSION['result'][]  = Array('title' => $title,'description'=> $description,'content_url' => $url,'icon' => $icon,'id'=> $id);
  ?>
  <li name="id" ><a href="show.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&name=<?php echo $title;?>">View doc</a></li>
  <?php
   $id++;
   ?>
```

**show.php**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
 $id = $_GET['id'];
?>  
<div> 
 <iframe  class="embed-responsive-item item" src="<?php echo   $_SESSION['result'][$id]['content_url'];?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

when i tried to check `$_SESSION['result']` i got this
[image]

this array should have contain only query results.Help me to fix it

Answer (score 1):

you're not setting the key of your array:

```
$_SESSION['result'] = Array();   
$_SESSION['result'][$id]  = Array('title' => $title,'description'=> $description,'content_url' => $url,'icon' => $icon,'id'=> $id);
```

add `session_start();` in your show.php

Comment: still showing same error when i'm trying to access $_SESSION['result'][$id]['title'] i.e unknown index result

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you have unwanted results.

This is basically because your are always adding results to the $_SESSION['results'] across all your queries.

Every time that you run search.php you will keep adding items to $_SESSION['result'], breaking the correspondence of the $id and the position of the array.

I would initialize the $_SESSION['result']

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $id = 1;
    $_SESSION['results'] = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    //...
    }
```